# Change alert message depending on language?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have created a newsletter pop-out feature, that allows the user to sign up to a newsletter that is sent out, there is a alert message if the user tries to click on submit without entering an email address first, however i need this message/alert to be changed according to the country they are on, for example if they are on the Italian site, i would need this message to be in Italian, my current code is:

```
this.signup = function() {
    if ($('#emailsignup').val() == '') {
       alert('Bitte geben Sie eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein.');
     } else {
           $.ajax({
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              data: {
                    e: $('#emailsignup').val(),
                    s: 'leftsideform',
                    c:  that.lang
                    },
                    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
                    url: 'http://karina.com/######',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.success === true) {
                            $('#emailsignup').val('');
                        }
                        if (response.callback.data != '') {
                             alert(response.callback.data);
                        }
                    }
           });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the frontend:

For me the simple way is to have a javascript generated by your back side (PHP for example) in order to have something like:

```
<script>
translation.error = "BLA BLA BLA";
</script>
```

That script will print that variables in the languages you want. Then in your code you only have to call it like this:

```
alert(window.translation.error);
```

To display the error in an alert.

Using your current code, you are passing the language variable to the server, and you want to return an error message if something went wrong. In your PHP you can have different files with different translations like:

```
/langs/en.php
/langs/it.php
/langs/...
```

With a structure like:

```
<?php
$trans = array("Error" => "Error message");
```

Depending on the language you can include one of the files and return the translated text like: $trans['error'].

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
   $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

   $langs_messages = array(
                         'ru' => 'Ru alert',
                         'en' => 'En alert',
                          // others langs 
                     );
   $lang_alert = $langs_message[$lang];
 ?>

 Javascript

 //.....
 if ($('#emailsignup').val() == '') {
                           alert('<?php echo $lang_alert; ?>');
 //.....
```